# Como descobrir se um array é multidimensional ou não em PHP?

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Tenho esses dois `arrays` abaixo:

```
 $a = [1, 2, 3];

 $b = [1,[2, [3, 4]]];
```

Sei que `$a` é um `array` unidimensional, e `$b`, multidimensional (array de arrays).

Agora, como eu poderia descobrir, através de uma função, que retornasse `boolean`, qual deles é multidimensional e qual não é?

Quero detectar se um array tem qualquer item com um `array` (isso já seria considerado multidimensional).

Comment: Acho que é [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/a/994599/1244639) que procura. Já precisei dessa verificação, caiu como uma luva.

Comment: @PapaCharlie essa eu conheço :D. Só que ela tem uma pequena falha. Se o `array` interno for vazio, ele vai reconhecer que o valor de `count` é igual

Comment: Não poderia contornar com um `array filter`? Não me recordo se cheguei a usar o filtro, depois vou ver na função.

Answer (score 3):

Uma técnica possível seria usando `count` para contar os valores do `array` e depois comparar com `count` usando o segundo parâmetro `COUNT_RECURSIVE`.

Só que esse método tem uma falha. Se o `array` tiver vazio, teremos um retorno inesperado :

```
$a = [1, 2]

$b = [1, []]

count($a) == count($a, COUNT_RECUSIVE); // true, não é multidimensional

count($b) == count($b, COUNT_RECUSIVE); // true, mas está errado, pois pelo fato de o `array` está vazio, não conta recursivamente.
```

Então qual é a solução?

Pensei em utilizar a função `gettype` combinado com `array_map` para contornar a situação:

```
 in_array("array", array_map('gettype', $a));

 in_array("array", array_map('gettype', $b));
```

A função `gettype` retornará o nome do tipo do valor passado. Combinando com `array_map`, ela vai usar essa função em cada elemento do `array`, retornando um `array` de nomes de tipos de variável.

A solução é apenas verificar se a palavra `"array"` está dentro desse `array` gerado. Se sim, é multidimensional.

Por questões de performance mostrada no próprio manual do PHP em relação a funçaõ `gettype`, podemos substituí-la por `is_array`. Porém teríamos que verificar se `true` existe no novo `array` gerado pelo `array_map`.

```
in_array(true, array_map('is_array', $b), true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de conseguir saber isso é usar `array_map()` para aplicar a função `is_array()` em cada elemento do array principal e somar os elementos do array de retorno, caso seja zero é um array simples caso seja maior que um é um array multidimensional.

```
<?php
   $b =  [1,[2, [3, 4]], ['a']];
   //$b =  [1,2,3];
   $a = array_sum(array_map('is_array', $b));
```

Comment: Eu tinha acabado de postar como complemento kkkkk +1

Comment: Mas você entendeu por que eu achei que `count` e `count recursive tem falhas, né?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters pq ele conta como elemento?

Comment: Na verdade, o pessoal compara o count recursive, pois ele contará mais elementos do que no count normal. Só que se o array interno estiver vazio, ele vai falar que não é recursivo